Excel VBA: Issue with SplitTextIntoColumns Macro - Runtime Error 1004
I'm working on an Excel VBA macro to split a single column of text into multiple columns using TextToColumns. The macro checks if the user selects only one column and then applies the TextToColumns method to split the text. However, I am encountering issues when running the macro:
Code:
Sub SplitTextIntoColumns()
    Dim destRng As Range
    
    If Selection.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        Set destRng = Columns("A:BZ")
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=destRng, _
            DataType:=xlDelimited, Space:=True
    Else
        MsgBox "select just one column"
    End If
End Sub

Problem:
The macro works when the selected range is a single column.
However, it triggers a Runtime Error 1004: Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error when attempting to split the text into columns.
What I Tried:
Changing the destination range from Columns("A:BZ") to something like Range("B1") or a specific range.
Ensuring the worksheet is unprotected and active.
Using Selection.EntireColumn instead of Selection.
Environment:
Excel 365
Windows 11
Question: What is causing the Runtime Error 1004 in this macro? How can I dynamically set the destination range for TextToColumns to handle any number of resulting columns without errors? Is there a better way to implement this functionality?
I want the selected column's text to be split into multiple columns dynamically, starting from the destination range specified in the macro.

The destination range just needs to be a single cell, if you use a larger range excel just uses the the top-left cell

^^^^Changing the destination to Range("B1") works for me.

If the user selects a range with multiple areas, Selection.Columns.Count will equal Selection.Areas(1).Columns.Count. As a result, Selection.Columns.Count = 1 might not correctly identify a multiple-column selection. I’ve added an additional If condition for better detection, which you can adjust as needed.
Also, please note that the Destination argument must be a valid cell reference.
Microsoft documentation:

Application.Intersect method (Excel)

Microsoft documentation:

Range.TextToColumns method (Excel)

Sub SplitTextIntoColumns()
    Dim destRng As Range, selRng As Range
    If Selection.Columns.Count = 1 And Selection.Areas.Count = 1 Then
        Set selRng = Intersect(Selection.EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        Set destRng = selRng.Cells(1)
        selRng.TextToColumns Destination:=destRng, _
            DataType:=xlDelimited, Space:=True
    Else
        MsgBox "select just one column"
    End If
End Sub

